# Copy data from a table in one postgres database to another, (different host names), using psql

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, psql

What code should I use if I want to execute a batch file with the psql copy command, (to transfer data from one postgres database table to another)?

How do I connect to the databases with two different host names at once?

How do I set the connection parameters?

I tried using this:

```
psql \
    -U user_name \
    -h production_server \
    -d database_name \
    -c "\\copy users to stdout" | \
psql -U user_name \
    -h staging_server \
    -d database_name \
    -c "\\copy users from stdin"
```

Comment: You can pipe `pg_dump` to `psql`: `pg_dump -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 -U your_user --schema='your_schema' --table='your_schema.your_table' your_db_name | psql -h other_host_ip -p 5432 -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U your_user your_db_name` (your_schema needs to be created on the target)

Comment: What happened when you tried using that?

Comment: Or you could use [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html) and not have to use a script or have simpler one that just does: `INSERT INTO local_tbl SELECT * FROM remote_tbl`.

Comment: Thank you for response Zegarek.I tried the method you proposed, unfortunately i’m get a error saying psql is not a recognised command.Not sure why because i have been using psql , the only thing missing was pg_dump which i had to download.These are the steps i took: 1) created a bat file 2) In the bat file i inputed with the example you provided and replaced with my values .One other question how can included the password parameter for both postgres databases(my source db and target db).Also do you know other methods of transferring data between two databases.